# Magnify in the cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I am having trouble getting `Magnify` to work in the cloud. When I generate two documents with

```
CloudDeploy[CreateDocument[ExpressionCell["x", "Output"]],"NormalX"];
CloudDeploy[CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Magnify["x", 5], "Output"]],"MagnifiedX"];
```

their appearance in the cloud is identical, even though in the locally-generated notebooks the latter `x` is appropriately magnified relative to the former. How can I get `Magnify` to work in the cloud?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magnify hasn't been implemented yet in the cloud.

You can test this by going to Mathematica online and evaluating:

```
ExpressionCell[Magnify["x", 5], "Output"]
```

I'm not sure what kind of workaround to give. It's important to understand why you want to have x be larger. Maybe creating an image would be a suitable workaround?

Comment: Is there a way to see this using something like CanonicalName@
 EntityList[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "CloudDevelopment"]]

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation to suggest there is.

Comment: Also, something like Magnify has multiple ways in which it works. It's possible for it to be partially implemented. I'm sure there's a ton of minor front end functionality, like Magnify, that incompletely implemented or works slightly differently.